# Elasticsearch error with an incomprehensible error message

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently trying out Elasticsearch. I've already made the first steps and installed it following the [official instructions](https://www.elastic.co/de/downloads/elasticsearch). But in my initial attempts, I get this incomprehensible error message. See this text below:

```
ÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöü
Ô£à Elasticsearch security features have been automatically configured!
Ô£à Authentication is enabled and cluster connections are encrypted.

Ôä╣´©Å  Password for the elastic user (reset with `bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic`):
  77kydX8WQaI6V5RXnEDB

Ôä╣´©Å  HTTP CA certificate SHA-256 fingerprint:
  b40aedc367164cf6d0f6a09ea2d6e6b258e41b94bbcd43db8f268238d590d472

Ôä╣´©Å  Configure Kibana to use this cluster:
ÔÇó Run Kibana and click the configuration link in the terminal when Kibana starts.
ÔÇó Copy the following enrollment token and paste it into Kibana in your browser (valid for the next 30 minutes):
  eyJ2ZXIiOiI4LjUuMyIsImFkciI6WyIxOTIuMTY4LjEuMTc5OjkyMDAiXSwiZmdyIjoiYjQwYWVkYzM2NzE2NGNmNmQwZjZhMDllYTJkNmU2YjI1OGU0MWI5NGJiY2Q0M2RiOGYyNjgyMzhkNTkwZDQ3MiIsImtleSI6IkFNZFBUNFVCenk4T19Mcy1lNmFvOmFoWnBnM1AtU3JDcEdlTXFPLS00M0EifQ==

Ôä╣´©Å  Configure other nodes to join this cluster:
ÔÇó On this node:
  Ôüâ Create an enrollment token with `bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node`.
  Ôüâ Uncomment the transport.host setting at the end of config/elasticsearch.yml.
  Ôüâ Restart Elasticsearch.
ÔÇó On other nodes:
  Ôüâ Start Elasticsearch with `bin/elasticsearch --enrollment-token <token>`, using the enrollment token that you generated.
ÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöüÔöü
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this message, when I try to run the Elasticsearch on port 9200:

```
[2022-12-26T17:55:47,141][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-VLBL46H] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:60933}
```

Comment: Are you trying HTTPS on your local?

Comment: @hkulekci yes local

Comment: I think the problem here, you are using https on your local, Could you be sure you are using HTTP request?